# Did Hyung Min-woo Invent Temozarela, the Antagonist of the "Priest" Manhwa?

Tags: symbolism, priest

One of the interest plot constructs in the *Priest* (manhwa) series by `Hyung Min-woo` is the antagonist [Temozarela](http://priest.wikia.com/wiki/Temozarela).

He is summarized as:

> Temozarela is an arch-angel who fought on God's side in the war
>   against Lucifer. However, this war caused God to lose faith in the
>   angels and prefer humanity instead.
>
> Temozarela, bitter at this, took twelve angels to Earth to prove to
>   God how flawed humans are. He set up a cult for the fallen angels
>   which involved human sacrifice. However, this only made God angry and
>   caused Temozarela to be banished to earth and imprisoned there.

[image: Temozarela as angel, human, and crippled human]
Left to Right: Temozarela as angel, human, and crippled human

Obviously there's some similarities to the whole angels parts of the *Preacher* comics, or various other fictional works, but all the similar ideas I found were still substantially different from `Temozarela`.

I did some Google searching as I was curious whether this character (`Temozarela`) was a wholly new creation of the author. I could find no prior source material, not under that name at least.

Does prior fictional or religious source material for `Temozarela` exist under the same name or alternate names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Temozarela is based off of the dark god Tchernobog from the Monolith game Blood, which the author admits is his inspiration for the basic setting of priest.

Comment: Hi Stuart, if you can add a supporting reference link that would be appreciated! :)